# Question about Sets of Divergence

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In Katznelson's Introduction to harmonic Analysis there is a theorem which follows from a lemma on p. 64 chapter 3

Theorem:
E is a Set of Divergence for B ( B is a homogenous Banach Space) if and only there exists an $  f \in B$ so that,

$$ S^*(f,t)= sup_n |S_n (f,t) | =\infty  $$
for  $ t \in E $

Lemma:
Let be $ g \in B$. There exists an Element $f \in B $ and a positive, even sequence $ \{ \Omega_j \} $ with $ \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \Omega_j = \infty $
so that $ \hat{f}(j) = \Omega_j \hat{g}(j)  $ for all $ j \in \mathbb{Z} $.

The Book says, the theorem is an easy consequence of the Lemma.
I don't understand why.
I would appreciate, if someone could explain it to me.
Thank you in advance